# Django Testing - authenticate() returns None

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, authentication

Working on making some unittests with Django, and trying to make some testing with the login process with the login form.

I am using modified `User` model just to make the email field unique; otherwise nothing drastically different.

## account/views.py

```
def post(self, request):
    # Retrieve the username and password
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    # Create a user object from authentication, or return None
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    # Check if user was created
    if user is not None:
        # Rest of the code, irrelevant...
```

## account/test_views.py

```
from account.models import User as CustomUser    

# Code snippit

def test_account_login_POST_successful_login(self):
    # Create a user to test login
    CustomUser.objects.create_user(
        username='test_user',
        email='test_user@intranet.com',
        password='flibble'
    )

    response = self.client.post(self.login_url, {
        'username': 'test_user',
        'password': 'flibble'
    })

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 301)
```

## account/models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Make the email field unique
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

## project/settings.py

```
# Authentication
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'
```

Funny thing is that login works normally on the web app, but when testing it always returns `None`.

I've tried to `check_password()` with the created user, and it returns true in both the test method and the view method.

I've also tried putting in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']`, but no go.

Comment: You're creating a `CustomUser` but you're using `account.User` as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Are both the same thing, imported under different names?

Comment: Yes, it was under an alias, but reverting CustomUser back to User still gives me the same result. I'll update the code showing the alias.

Comment: Somehow I was able to solve this, but I am not sure what might had fixed the issue. Sorry if that is not helpful for any that might have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem. The problem was in `is_active` model field. In my case this field was `False` by default, so `authenticate()` returns `None` all the time.